# nextElementSibling but only within div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement the word rotation app from this https://codepen.io/stevenlei/pen/RwpRgzy. on a landing page. The problem I'm running into is that the `nextElementSibling` variable continues on its own, passing the `div` container that I would like to keep it in. I've attempted to make the instructions and apply an `if` statement with a flag if is available.

The full code can be found here [github](https://github.com/gerlinp/gerlinp.github.io)

```js
setInterval(function () {
  const show = document.querySelector('span[data-show]')
  const next = show.nextElementSibling || document.querySelector('span:first-child')
  const up = document.querySelector('span[data-up]')
  
  if (up) {
    up.removeAttribute('data-up')
  }
  
  show.removeAttribute('data-show')
  show.setAttribute('data-up', '')
  
  next.setAttribute('data-show', '')
}, 2000)
```

```css
:root {
  --offset: 6px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
  width: 980px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  line-height: 1.06;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  color: #1d1d1f;
}

.mask {
  height: 106px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: var(--offset);
}

.mask span {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: var(--offset);
  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mask span[data-show] {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: .5s transform ease-in-out;
}

.mask span[data-up] {
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  transition: .5s transform ease-in-out;
}

.mask span:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #0ecffe 50%, #07a6f1);
}

.mask span:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #18e198 50%, #0ec15d);
}

.mask span:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #8a7cfb 50%, #633e9c);
}

.mask span:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #fa7671 50%, #f45f7f);
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Turn your living room into
  <div class="mask">
    <span data-show>a theater.</span>
    <span>a gym.</span>
    <span>a concert hall.</span>
    <span>an arcade.</span>
  </div>
</h2>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `nextElementSibling` will be `null` if the element doesn't have a next sibling. It does "continue outside" the parent element. Does the code here replicate your issue? What's the expected behavior?

Comment: Due to " const next = show.nextElementSibling || document.querySelector('span:first-child')" it loops due to or rule that if it cant find a nextelementsibling it will then proceed to the span:first-child.  You can see a live version here https://gerlinp.github.io/. if you look at the console it goes beyond the mask class and gets stuck on my navbar.

Comment: Yes, but that's due to `document.querySelector('span:first-child')` then, not `nextElementSibling`. You have to use the right selector to choose the first mask again (e.g. in your example here `.mask span:first-child`).

Comment: you are mixing the concept of sibling and child here. Thats probably confusing you.

Comment: with this line `const next = show.nextElementSibling || document.querySelector('span:first-child')` if show has a sibling it will break out of the container even though that was probably not your intention. Now its looping on shows sibling and not shows children. Maybe use nextElementChild instead